# How to match identifiers NOT all consisted by numbers?

Tags: regex, antlr, matching, identifier, lexer

I have the following lexer: `ID : [a-z][a-z0-9_]*;`

It works well except matching identifiers like `1a` or `222z222`, but not all numbers like `1` or `999`.

So, what should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Could you please explain clearly by examples what you want to match and what you don't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lexer is `[a-z][a-z0-9_]*`. So this will match which **starts with lowercase letter, followed by zero or more lowercase letters or digits or underscore**

if you want the identifiers to start with either lowercase or digit but not all digits, then try

```
[a-z][a-z0-9_]*;|[0-9]+[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*;  // Updated
```

---

So it got two parts

- `[a-z][a-z0-9_]*;` : matched which starts with lowercase
- `[0-9]+[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*;` : if it starts with digits, the after one or more digits, it expects one letter or underscore, followed by zero or more letter, digit or underscore.

You can write the same thing as `([a-z]|[0-9]+[a-z_])[a-z0-9_]*;`.

Comment: But it can also match `1234`, which is a number not an indentifier.

Comment: Your identifier can start with number, but not all numbers, right? I understood it wrong. I'm working on it.

Comment: @WAKU : I've updated the answer. See whether this solves your purpose.